# How can I replace byte sequences in my data using Sed?

Tags: string, bash, replace, sed, makefile

I have this rule in my Makefile, to replace `|||` (three pipe characters; hex `7c 7c 7c`) with <kbd>CR</kbd><kbd>LF</kbd><kbd>NUL</kbd> (carriage return + line feed + null; hex `0d 0a 00`):

```
rom.hex: rom.txt  
    hexdump -C rom.txt | cut -c10-60 > rom.hex
    sed -i -e 's/  / /g' rom.hex
    sed -i -e 's/7c 7c 7c/0d 0a 00/g' rom.hex
```

This works some of the time - but, if the output of `hexdump` splits a `7c 7c 7c` sequence across two lines it isn't matched by sed.

The replacement has to be the same length as the match, so as not to shift the subsequent bytes.

Comment: What is `the string "|||"`? Edit your question to clarify your requirements and post some concise, testable sample input and expected output as right now it's not even clear what the question is about - modifying the chain of commands in your makefile so they work when written on separate lines or write a script to be called from the makefile do something with text that's split across lines. Is the issue split lines in your makefile or split lines in a file being operated on by your makefile?

Comment: Assuming that you need to preserve _all_ input bytes in the output, use `hexdump -v`, otherwise duplicates in blocks of adjacent identical lines are printed as `*`, resulting in loss of information. This command illustrates the problem: `hexdump -C  <(printf '%*s' 64 ' ')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make the replacement first, before transforming into hex:

```
rom.hex: rom.txt
    sed -e 's/|||/\r\n\x00/g' $< | hexdump -v | cut -c'10-60' >$@
```

---

Note that the backslash escapes are a GNU sed extension, so this is not a completely portable solution.  If you need a portable sed command, you'll need to put it in a separate file, because you can't include a NUL in a command-line argument.  The literal newline must be quoted, too:

```
s/|||/^M\
^@/g
```

For clarity, the control characters above are

```
73 2f 7c 7c 7c 2f 0d 5c  0a 00 2f 67      |s/|||/.\../g|
```

Then the rule would be

```
rom.hex: rom.txt
    sed -f "transform.sed" $< | hexdump -v | cut -c'10-60' >$@
```

Comment: ++ for a clever solution additionally simplified with special `make` variables `$<` and `$@`; the OP also seems to use _GNU_ `sed`, so I don't expect it to be a problem, but it should be noted that your `sed` command requires it.

Comment: It looks like 3-digit octal escapes don't work in GNU `sed`, use `\x7c` instead. Similarly, you must use `\x00` in the replacement string to produce an actual NUL byte. Given that you can simply use `|` literals instead of `\x7c`, we can simplify to: `sed 's/|||/\r\n\x00/g'` (still not portable; `sed 's/|||/'$'\r\\\n\x00'/g` _almost_ works (assuming `bash`, `ksh`, `zsh`), but the NUL byte generated by `$'...'` is _eaten_ by the shell when synthesizing the complete `sed` script).

Comment: Kudos for the background information on portability; regrettably, BSD `sed` doesn't like the NUL even inside a file: `sed -f <(printf 's/|||/\r\\\n\x00/g') <<<'a|||b'` works fine with GNU `sed`, but breaks with BSD `sed` with `unterminated substitute in regular expression`. The only option I see is to use a 2-pass solution: substitute a different char. first, then use `tr` to translate it to NUL; e.g. `sed 's/|||/'$'\r\\\n\x01'/g <<<'a|||b' | tr '\1' '\0'`

Comment: I relied on GNU `sed --posix` to check my script - I can't vouch for it myself.  The two-pass solution likely has the problem that there's no "can't happen" character in the ROM image...  :-(

Comment: Good point re "can't happen" character - bummer. The [`sed` POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) is silent on the issue of `NUL` in replacement strings, so I guess that means it's implementation-defined.

Comment: not to be ungrateful or anything ! but you missed -C from hexdump.  sed first makes the whole thing simpler.... nice solution...

Comment: @ChrisCamacho: There is no reason to use `-C`, because all it adds is the ASCII column at the end, which you ignore anyway due to your `cut` command.

Comment: @TobySpeight: It may be worth adding `-v` to `hexdump` to ensure that no information is lost if adjacent lines happen to end up identical.

Comment: @ChrisCamacho: What platform is this? It's generally worth mentioning your platform in your question, especially if it is out of the ordinary (for instance, you used _GNU_ `sed` features without saying so). Given that Toby solved your problem with the `sed` command alone, that point is ultimately moot, however.

Answer (score 2):

<sup>- [Toby Speight's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35783255/45375) elegantly bypasses the OP's problem by using *GNU* `sed` to replace data *at the source*, without needing to operate on a hex. representation (his portable alternative doesn't work with BSD `sed`, but that's only because of the `NUL` character in the replacement string).

- The value of *this* answer is in solving the OP's problem *exactly as stated*, notably using `tr -s '\n' ' '`, and in providing a relatively simple *portable* solution at the bottom - it is of interest from a byte-represenation / text processing perspective.

- See [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35785460/45375) for a *simpler* solution that uses *`hexdump`'s formatting options* to produce the desired output format *directly*.</sup>

---

**Note**:

- The solutions below transform the byte-value representation of the input into a *single* line, so as to enable robust use of `sed` to replace values.
- If you do want the fixed-width multi-line output that `hexdump` produces by default, pipe the output to `... | fmt -w48`

---

The following command normalizes all whitespace in the output from `hexdump -C`:

```
hexdump -vC rom.txt | cut -c10-60 | tr -s '\n' ' ' > rom.hex
```

<sup>Note the **addition of `-v`**, which **prevents loss of information**.

Without `-v`, duplicates in adjacent repeating lines would be represented as `*`.</sup>

The result is:

- a *single line* bookended by a leading and trailing space,

  - <sup>If you want to strip these, see the portable solution at the bottom.</sup>
- with *byte values all separated by a single space each*; e.g.:
  `23 21 2f 62 69 6e 2f 62 61 73 68 0a 0a 23 20 23 20 76 3d 24 5f 0a 23 20 23 20 65 63 68 6f 20 22 ...`.
- Note that `tr`'s `-s` ("squeeze") option, *after* having performed the translation (`\n` to  in this case, i.e.), folds runs of multiple occurrences of the target character ( (space) in this case) into single-character runs.

Thus:

- The intermediate `sed` command (`sed -i -e 's/  /...`) to normalize the line-internal spaces is no longer needed.
- The final `sed` command (`sed -i -e 's/7c 7c 7c/ ...`) can safely use space-separated values as the search string, without worrying about where the line breaks happened to be in `hexdump -C`'s output.

There is room for **simplification**:

- A single pipeline can be used - no need to write to the file in an intermediate form and update it in place later.

  - As a side effect, because `-i` is no longer needed, the `sed` command becomes portable (POSIX-compliant); while this form will work on both Linux and BSD/OSX platforms, it is still not strictly POSIX-compliant as a whole, because `hexdump` is a nonstandard utility; see the bottom for a strictly POSIX-compliant solution.
- Special `make` variables `$<`, the (first) prerequisite (`rom.hex`), and `$@`, the target (`rom.txt`) can be used.
- There is no need for the `-C` option of `hexdump`, if only the byte values are needed; this allows simplification of the `cut` command, which, incidentally, strips the *leading* space from the output (and also makes `tr`'s `-s` option unnecessary):

```
rom.hex: rom.txt  
    hexdump -v $< | cut -sd' ' -f2- | tr '\n' ' ' | sed 's/7c 7c 7c/0d 0a 00/g' > $@
```

- `cut -sd' ' -f2-`:

  - `-s` means that lines not containing the delimiter (separator) specified with `-d` are skipped, which skips a trailing empty line (empty except for the byte-offset column) that `hexdump` may output.
  - `-d' '` splits the input into fields using a single space as the delimiter.
  - `-f2-` outputs the 2nd field through the end of the line (`-`), effectively stripping the 1st field (the input-address *offset* column in `hexdump`'s output).

---

To make the command **fully portable**, POSIX utility `od` can be used in lieu of the nonstandard `hexdump` utility.
Furthermore, an extra `sed` command is used to **strip the leading and trailing space from the output**.

```
rom.hex: rom.txt  
    od -t x1 -A n -v $< | tr -s '\n' ' ' | sed 's/^ //; s/ $//' | sed 's/7c 7c 7c/0d 0a 00/g' > $@
```

- `od -t x1 -A n -v` outputs hex. (`x`) bytes (`1`) across multiple lines of fixed width, similar to `hexdump`, except that `-A n` blanks out the input-address offset column; `-v` ensures that all bytes are represented; without it, adjacent duplicate lines would be represented as `*`.
- `tr -s '\n' ' '`, as above, normalizes the whitespace to produce a single, long line with byte values separated by a single space, bookended by a single leading and trailing space.
- `sed 's/^ //; s/ $//'` removes the leading and trailing space.
- The rest of the command is as before.

Comment: What is the advantage of using `tr -s '\n' ' '` versus `tr -d '\n'`? Aren't they equivalent in this case or did I miss something?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: They're _not_ equivalent: the `-s` ensures that, _after_ translation of `\n` to ` ` has been performed, runs of multiple spaces are normalized to a single space each. For instance, `tr -s '\n' ' ' <<<$'a\n   \n   b'` yields `a<space>b<space>`.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>- See [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35782706/45375) for how to solve the problem *as stated* or if you need a *POSIX-compliant* solution.

- *This* answer is of interest from a *byte-representation formatting* perspective.</sup>

---

**Note**:

- The solutions below transform the byte-value representation of the input into a *single* line, so as to enable robust use of `sed` to replace values.
- If you do want the fixed-width multi-line output that `hexdump` produces by default, pipe the output to `... | fmt -w48`

---

The **problem can be bypassed** by passing **formatting options to `hexdump`**:

```
hexdump -ve '1/1 "%02x "'
```

produces the desired output format as a *single* line directly (there will be a single trailing space).

- `-v` prevents abbreviation of repeating bytes as `*`
- `-e '1/1 "%02x "'`:

  - `1/1` specifies that the following format string be applied to 1 unit of byte size 1, i.e., each byte.
  - `"%02x "` is the format string to apply to each byte: a 2-digit hex number followed by a space.

To put it all together, using special `make` variables `$<`, the (first) prerequisite (`rom.hex`), and `$@`, the target (`rom.txt`):

```
rom.hex: rom.txt  
    hexdump -ve '1/1 "%02x "' $< | sed 's/7c 7c 7c/0d 0a 00/g' > $@
```

---

Alternative solution, **using the (also nonstandard) `xxd` utility**; like `hexdump`, however, it is available on both Linux and BSD/OSX:

```
rom.hex: rom.txt  
    xxd -p $< | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/../& /g; s/ $//' | sed 's/7c 7c 7c/0d 0a 00/g' > $@
```

- `xxd -p` prints a stream of byte values *without separators*, broken into lines of fixed length.
- `tr -d '\n'` removes the newlines from the output.
- `sed 's/../& /g; s/ $//'` inserts a space after every 2 characters, then deletes the trailing space at the end of the line.

---

Finally, as [Toby Speight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4850040/toby-speight) points out in a [since cleaned-up] comment, you can use the ***GNU* version of `od`** with the nonstandard `-w` option:

```
rom.hex: rom.txt  
    od -t x1 -A n -w1 -v $< | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/7c 7c 7c/0d 0a 00/g' > $@
```

- `od -t x1 -A n -w1 -v` outputs hex. (`x`) bytes (`1`) 1 byte at a time (`-w1`); `-A n` omits the input-address offset column; `-v` ensures that all bytes are represented; without it, adjacent duplicate lines would be represented as `*`.
- `tr -d '\n'` simply removes all newlines, and since each line starts with a space, the result is a single long line with a leading space.